# Jenkins Pipeline: Build docker within docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to do the following

1. Checkout the code
2. Do some prechecks using some other docker images (don't want to install these on Jenkins node)
3. Build jar using docker image `maven:3.6-jdk-8`
4. Then run `Dockerfile` to build app image
5. Push the image to repository

Now, I don't want to install anything apart from Docker on Jenkins node. I want to run the full pipeline in Docker container to achieve this. What I'm struggling is how to build the 4th step from within the container.

I wrote the Jenkinsfile as below

```
pipeline {

    agent none
    
    stages {
        stage('Maven build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.6-jdk-8'
                    args '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            steps {
                checkout(
                    [
                        $class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [
                            [name: '*/master']
                        ],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                        extensions: [], 
                        submoduleCfg: [], 
                        userRemoteConfigs: [
                            [
                                credentialsId: '<cred-id>',
                                url: '<github-url>']
                            ]
                        ])
                        
                sh '''
                    set -eux pipefail

                    mvn -e clean install
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build docker image') {
             // Which docker image to use?
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to build a docker image within container.  The search didn't help that much. I tried using the Jenkins node for the docker image building but it seems I cannot mix and match. I totally understand this is quite an open question but I think it would be helpful to know the straightforward answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Jenkins Plugin:  https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow